# Weird behavior in PyCharm when pressing "|" on Mac

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> it usually result as "|" in my usual workflow. But I'm using PyCharm community and it does some sort "insertion" by looking-up/matching a previous word from where my caret is currently at. Also if I do <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, I get forward word lookup instead. You can get an idea of the behavior from this GIF:

[image: Pycharm weird shortcut behavior]

I tried to look-up in my keymaps but couldn't find anything that does this behavior.

Note: My current keymaps settings are mostly identical from the default macOS keymaps template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, simply click on the magnify glass on the right of the search bar to search by combination of press when editing the keymaps.

The function name was "Cyclic Expand Word":

[image]

Note: Sadly this still cause an issue in the console, but that does the main job.